# In assembly, what does `PTR` stand for?

Tags: assembly, x86

```
and     dword ptr [ebp-4], 0
```

In assembly code like above, what does *the term* `PTR` stand for?
I know their usage -- size directives; but where had *the term* `PTR` been coined from? Does it stand for `PoinTeR`?

I've read:

- [What does `dword ptr` mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987876/what-does-dword-ptr-mean)
- [x86 Assembly Guide](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html)
- [Meaning of the [] and PTR operators???](https://www.programmersheaven.com/discussion/138516/meaning-of-the-and-ptr-operators)

Comment: It stands for pointer.

Comment: Probably Totally Random

Comment: Ptr Term Required

Comment: One instance where ptr doesn't quite make sense, is when pushing an immediate value, such as | push dword ptr 012345678h | . The syntax implies that a pointer is being pushed onto the stack, but the immediate value doesn't actually have to be a pointer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The point of this hint is to tell the size of the operand.

You're writing to a point in memory. As you're only giving a 0, it doesn't know if it should write a byte, or word, or doubleword. The `dword ptr` means "write a doubleword". Yes, it stands for pointer, because you put a memory address as destination.

Comment: Why is PTR required? Why isn't DWORD sufficient to infer the size of the operand? Is this just a syntatical quirk?

Comment: @jonny Yes, it is pretty much a syntactical quirk. Most modern (Intel-compatible) assemblers would accept `and [ebp-4], 0`, `and  dword [ebp-4], 0` and `and  dword ptr [ebp-4], 0` as the same.

Comment: @Toothbrush: good assemblers will reject `and [ebp-4], 0` as ambiguous operand-size: do you want to zero a byte, word, dword, or qword.  [Determining when NASM can infer the size of the mov operation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30959266). Less-good assemblers have a default, often dword (like GAS for non-mov insns); with really bad assemblers like emu8086, the size depends on the numeric constant!!!  Also, there aren't any assemblers AFAIK that will accept both `dword` and `dword ptr`.  MASM will assemble `dword` as the constant number 4, so `4[ebp-4]` = `[ebp - 4 + 4]` = `[ebp]`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I've seen and used both `DWORD` and `DWORD PTR` in NASM and LLVM (Intel-syntax) assembly blocks. I'm not so sure about the `and [ebp-4], 0` syntax; I'm pretty sure I've used it in NASM in the past.

Comment: @Toothbrush: NASM and GNU .intel_syntax are different.  NASM chokes on `dword ptr`, GAS / LLVM choke on `dword`.  With NASM 2.15.05 assembling MASM/GNU syntax: `warning: 'ptr' is not a NASM keyword [-w+ptr]` / `error: symbol 'ptr' not defined`.  And for clang/LLVM assembling NASM syntax, we get `error: Expected 'PTR' or 'ptr' token!`.  With actual GAS, we get `Error: ambiguous operand size for 'add'` from `add dword [ebp - 4], 0`, but with `add dword [ebp-4], eax` the disassembly is `add dword ptr [ebp+0], eax`.

Comment: @Toothbrush: As for `and [ebp-4], 0` without a size specifier, no, current NASM definitely rejects that: `error: operation size not specified`.  Older NASM might have been bad and had some default, but more likely you're mis-remembering.  (Older GAS didn't use to error or warn about ambiguous operand-size on instructions other than mov; I think that was a change in the past few months.  But not for NASM.)

Comment: For MASM-style syntaxes like MASM or GAS `.intel_syntax`, the failure mode is far worse if the operand-size wasn't ambiguous: `add dword [rdi], eax` is `add [rdi+4], eax` with size implied by EAX, so it silently accepts the typo as something you almost certainly didn't mean.  `dword` is a constant with value 4 in some contexts, including this one.  The `ptr` part is necessary to indicate a memory operand because brackets don't do that in MASM when there's no register: see *[Confusing brackets in MASM32](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25129743)*