# Key Differences Between `mov byte ptr` and `mov word ptr`

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, tasm, emu8086

I've been reading past posts on

1. What `ptr` does?
2. What `[]` does?

in assembly, but I'm still struggling to understand the following code:

```
    Title : Program failed to comprehend
    .model small
    .stack 100h
    .data
         Msg db 10,13, 'Zahid. $'   
    .code
    .startup
         ; Initialising data segment
          mov ax, @data
          mov dx, ax
        ;Before operation displaying message
         mov dx, offset msg
         mov ah,09h
         int 21h

          mov msg , 'A'          ; Writing on memory specified by msg thats OK -> A
          mov msg+1 , 'R'     ; Confusion as writing on memory specified by msg then add 1(not 8bits next address write) -> A
          mov [msg]+2, 'I'     ; confusion: Writing on memory specified by msg then add 2 value to that address write-> I
          mov byte ptr [msg+3] , 'F'      ; Ok with me, writing on byte memory specified by msg+3 -> F 
          mov word ptr [msg + 4], '.'      ; Confused again as writing on word memory specified by msg+4, '.' Will it write ascii on the two bytes-> .
          mov msg[5] , '$'   ; Not confused on this.
  
       ;Print var
        mov dx, offset msg
        mov ah,09h
        int 21h
     
        ;Exit Code.
        mov ah,04ch
        xor al,al
        int 21h
         
    Ends
```

Output:
`Zahid.  ARIF.`

Please explain the operation as I believe it should not print 'ARIF'??

Comment: What are you expecting it to print? It's quite clear just from looking at the code and comments that it should be printing something like `'Arif'` (*Although I would expect this to be uppercase*). Even contains the characters `ARIF.` in the code.

Comment: The output should be `\n\rZahid. ARIF.` You either didn't post exact output, or code. EDIT: you actually have the DOS newline 13,10 bytes in wrong order, so the output will start `\n\r`, not `\r\n`. What is your question exactly?

Comment: Why mov [msg] +2 , 'I'  didnt produce error. Because [msg] will return address of variable then increment it by 2 and initialise that address by some value should not produce 'i' on execution

Comment: the emu8086 and MASM (and TASM in MASM emulation mode) have quite relaxed syntax, all these are equivalent in MASM: `mov msg+2,'I'`, `mov [msg+2],'I'`, `mov [msg]+2,'I'`, `mov byte ptr [msg+2],'I'`, `mov [2+msg],'I'`, `mov msg[2],'I'` (not sure about this one and I don't have emu8086 to verify) ... basically as long as on one side is memory operand, it's memory operand. Check Intel instruction reference guide to see what are the valid memory operands, especially in 16 bit real mode they are very limited. (the `byte ptr` is not needed, because `msg` was defined by `db`, MASM recognized that)

Comment: But the "correct" Intel syntax is `mov [msg+2],'I'` and you have to specify the datum size, in NASM for example `mov byte [msg+2], 'I'` or `mov [msg+2], byte 'I'` .. as you can see, each assembler may have subtle differences/dialects. Usually if you are not experienced enough to recognize all those quirks, you may want to produce listing file (I think it's new feature of emu8086 from last version, and normal feature of stand-alone assemblers), where you can check after assembly what instruction was produced + it's opcode.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129743/confusing-brackets-in-masm32.  "square brackets `[]` mean pretty much nothing to MASM when you're just using symbols. They only mean something when you use them with registers."  (MASM / TASM  / emu8086 are all the same on this, AFAIK).

Comment: It's not clear what you think each instruction should do, i.e. how the syntax in each line should translate to machine code.  Please [edit] your question to say what you think the syntax means.  What kind of answer are you looking for?  Something like Ross's answer on the question I linked, explaining that `[]` is optional with symbol names?  This is nearly a duplicate of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In assembly the syntax depends on particular assembler. Emu8086 is mostly following MASM dialect, which is quite relaxed in rules and allows for several different [options (with same output)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129743/confusing-brackets-in-masm32).

If you are used to some high level programming language, this may feel confusing, why the syntax is not set in stone and how to live with this mess in asm.

But for asm programmer this is rarely an issue, because in assembly you don't build some runtime expression with operators and different values, instruction from source is usually 1:1 mapped to one of CPU instructions, with the exact arguments and options of the particular instruction which exists in CPU.

The [`MOV` instruction](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_176.html) on x86 is a bit mess itself, as it is single mnemonics "MOV" used for many different instruction opcodes, but in your example only two instructions are used: `MOV r/m8,imm8` with opcode `C6` for storing byte values, and `MOV r/m16,imm16` with opcode `C7` to store word value. And in all cases that `r/m` part is memory reference by absolute offset, which is calculated during compile time.

So if `msg` is symbol for memory address `0x1000`, then those lines in your question compile as:

```
; machine code  | disassembled instruction from machine code

C606001041        mov byte [0x1000],0x41
```

Store byte value `0x41` (`'A'`) into memory at address `ds:0x1000`. The `C6 06` is `MOV [offset16],imm8` instruction opcode, the `00 10` bytes are `0x1000` offset16 itself (little endian) and finally the `41` is the imm8 value `0x41`. Segment `ds` will be used to calculate full physical memory address by default, because there's no segment override prefix ahead of that instruction.

```
C606011052        mov byte [0x1001],0x52
C606021049        mov byte [0x1002],0x49
C606031046        mov byte [0x1003],0x46
C70604102E00      mov word [0x1004],0x2e
C606051024        mov byte [0x1005],0x24
```

Remaining lines are the same story, writing byte values at specific memory offsets, going byte by byte in memory, overwriting every one of them.

With the subtle difference of `mov word ptr [msg + 4], '.'`, which does target memory address `ds:0x1004` similarly like other lines, but the value stored is `imm16`, i.e. `word` value, equal to `0x002E` (`'.'`), so the different opcode `C7` is used, and the immediate value needs two bytes `2E 00`. This one will overwrite memory at address `ds:0x1004` with byte `2E`, and `ds:0x1005` with byte `00`.

So if the memory at address `msg` (`ds:0x1000` in my examples) was at the beginning:

```
0x1000: 0A 0D 5A 61 68 69 64 2E 20 24  ; "\n\rZahid. $"
```

It will change to this after each `MOV` executed:

```
0x1000: 41 0D 5A 61 68 69 64 2E 20 24  ; "A\rZahid. $"
0x1000: 41 52 5A 61 68 69 64 2E 20 24  ; "ARZahid. $"
0x1000: 41 52 49 61 68 69 64 2E 20 24  ; "ARIahid. $"
0x1000: 41 52 49 46 68 69 64 2E 20 24  ; "ARIFhid. $"
0x1000: 41 52 49 46 2E 00 64 2E 20 24  ; "ARIF.\0d. $"
```

That word did overwrite two bytes, both `'h'` (with dot) and `'i'` (with zero).

```
0x1000: 41 52 49 46 2E 24 64 2E 20 24  ; "ARIF.$d. $"
```

And that zero is overwritten one more time to dollar sign (string terminator for the DOS `int 21h` service `ah=9`).

Generally the relaxed syntax is not a problem, because you can't build your own instruction, the assembler will guess which one of the existing ones fits, and compile whatever expression you have into it. There's no instruction on x86 like `mov [address1] and [address2], value` storing same value at two different memory locations, or `mov [address]+2` which would add two to the memory value at `address` (that's possible to do with `add [address], 2` which is one off the [`add r/m,imm` variants](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_5.html), depending on the data size).

So `mov msg+1,...` can be only memory address `msg + 1`, there's no other meaningful possibility in x86 instruction set. And the data size `byte` is deducted from the `db` directive used after label `msg:`, this is speciality of MASM and emu8086 assemblers, most of the other assemblers don't link any defined label (symbol) with directive used after it, i.e. no "types" of symbols in common assemblers. For those the `mov msg+1,'R'` may end with syntax error, but not because the left side is problematic, but they will not know how big the `'R'` value should be (how many bytes).

My personal favourite NASM would report another error on it, as it requires the brackets around memory access, so in NASM only `mov [msg+2],...` would be valid (with size modifier like "byte ptr" in MASM allowed, but without "ptr": `mov byte [msg+2],...`. But in MASM/emu8086 all the variants you used are valid syntax with same meaning, producing memory reference by 16b offset.

The assembler will also not produce two instructions instead of single (exception may be special "pseudo-instructions" in some assemblers, which are compiled to several native instructions, but that is not common in x86 assembly).

Once you know the target CPU instruction set, what instructions do exist, you will be able to guess from the vague syntax easily, which target instruction will be produced.

Or you can easily check in debugger disassembly window, as the disassembler will use only single way of syntax for particular instruction, not aware of the source formatting ambiguities.

> ```
>  mov word ptr [msg + 4], '.'
>    ; Confused again as writing on word memory specified by msg+4,
>      '.' Will it write ascii on the two bytes-> .
> ```

It will write on two bytes, that's what `WORD PTR` in MASM specifies. But the value is only `'.' = 0x2E`. But `0x2E` is perfectly valid even as 16 bit value, simply extended with zeroes to `0x002E`, and that's the value used by the assembler for this line.

In future, if you are not sure, how particular thing assembles, and what it will do to the CPU/memory state, just use the emu8086 debugger. If you would in this case, you would see in the disassembly window that all those variants of `msg+x` did compile to the memory addresses going byte by byte over original `msg` memory. Also if you would open some memory view (I hope emu8086 has one, I don't use it) at `msg` address, you could watch each write to memory, how it does change the original values, and how that `WORD PTR` works, as you were not sure. Watching in debugger is usually lot more easier than reading these long answers on stack overflow...

About what PTR does: [In assembly, what does `PTR` stand for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41562732/in-assembly-what-does-ptr-stand-for)  ... doesn't explain it well, as it's hard to explain it well, the whole "BYTE PTR" is the term used by MASM, it's not parsing it as BYTE and then doing something PTR to the BYTE, but it will parse it as "BYTE PTR" and be like "okay, he want to address byte". It's like single keyword, but with space.