# x86 Assembly pointers

Tags: pointers, assembly, x86

I am trying to wrap my mind around pointers in Assembly.

What exactly is the difference between:

```
mov eax, ebx
```

and

```
mov [eax], ebx
```

and when should `dword ptr [eax]` should be used?

Also when I try to do `mov eax, [ebx]` I get a compile error, why is this?

Comment: `mov eax, ebx` moves the value in register _EBX_ to _EAX_ . The `mov [eax], ebx` moves the 32-bit value in _EBX_ to the memory location   that _EAX_ is pointing at.

Comment: Ok so just to make sure I am understanding this correctly. The following code:

`int a;

_asm {
     mov [a], eax`

will copy the value stored in eax into the memory location that int a is pointing to?

If I proceed to print value of a, will I see the value that was stored in eax?

Also, if I do the following instead:
`int a = 5;

_asm{
    mov [eax], a
`

Whats going on there? Is eax storing memory location of a? or is it storing 5?

Comment: @Duxa: It is not that simple. If we assume that `a` is a variable, then `mov [a],ebx` will write the value in ebx to that variable (`a` is seen as an address too). Some compilers will also allow `mov a,ebx` to do the same, others will not. But `eax` is a register, so it is not a variable. `mov [eax],ebx` is not the same as `mov eax,ebx`. The former will store ebx in the address pointed to by eax, the latter will store ebx in eax.

Comment: Rudy I think you may have just cleared up a huge point of confusion for me. I am using Visual Studio (inline assembly) and was trying to figure out the difference between `mov a, eax` and `mov [a], eax`. When looking at registers and local values they were identical... so you are saying that they are identical? Great to know!

Comment: In MASM syntax the brackets `[]` are ignored unless they contain the name of a register.

Comment: Thanks! This clarified a lot for me. Now last thing Im not understanding why I cant do `mov a, [eax]` Should that not make "a" a pointer to wherever eax is pointing?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

As has already been stated, wrapping brackets around an operand means that that operand is to be *dereferenced*, as if it were a pointer in C. In other words, the brackets mean that you are reading a value *from* (or storing a value *into*) that memory location, rather than reading that value directly.

So, this:

```
mov  eax, ebx
```

simply copies the value in `ebx` into `eax`. In a pseudo-C notation, this would be: `eax = ebx`.

Whereas this:

```
mov  eax, [ebx]
```

dereferences the contents of `ebx` and stores the pointed-to value in `eax`. In a pseudo-C notation, this would be: `eax = *ebx`.

Finally, this:

```
mov  [eax], ebx
```

stores the value in `ebx` into the memory location pointed to by `eax`. Again, in pseudo-C notation: `*eax = ebx`.

---

The registers here could also be replaced with memory operands, such as symbolic variable names. So this:

```
mov  eax, [myVar]
```

dereferences the address of the variable `myVar` and stores the *contents* of that variable in `eax`, like `eax = myVar`.

By contrast, this:

```
mov  eax, myVar
```

stores the *address* of the variable `myVar` into `eax`, like `eax = &myVar`.

At least, that's how *most* assemblers work. Microsoft's assembler (called MASM), and the Microsoft C/C++ compiler's inline assembly, is a bit different. It treats the above two instructions as equivalent, essentially *ignoring* the brackets around memory operands.

To get the address of a variable in MASM, you would use the `OFFSET` keyword:

```
mov  eax, OFFSET myVar
```

However, even though MASM has this forgiving syntax and allows you to be sloppy, you shouldn't. Always include the brackets when you want to dereference a variable and get its actual value. You will never get the wrong result if you write the code explicitly using the proper syntax, and it'll make it easier for others to understand. Plus, it'll force you to get into the habit of writing the code the way that other assemblers will expect it to be written, rather than relying on MASM's "do what I mean, not what I write" crutch.

Speaking of that "do what I mean, not what I write" crutch, MASM also generally allows you to get away with omitting the operand-size specifier, since it knows the size of the variable. But again, I recommend writing it for clarity and consistency. Therefore, if `myVar` is an `int`, you would do:

```
mov  eax, DWORD PTR [myVar]    ; eax = myVar
```

or

```
mov  DWORD PTR [myVar], eax    ; myVar = eax
```

This notation is [*necessary* in other assemblers like NASM](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/archive/mp/f99/mp5/masm_nasm.html) that are not strongly-typed and don't remember that `myVar` is a `DWORD`-sized memory location.

You don't need this at all when dereferencing register operands, since the name of the register indicates its size. `al` and `ah` are always `BYTE`-sized, `ax` is always `WORD`-sized, `eax` is always `DWORD`-sized, and `rax` is always `QWORD`-sized. But it doesn't hurt to include it anyway, if you like, for consistency with the way you notate memory operands.

---

> Also when I try to do `mov eax, [ebx]` I get a compile error, why is this?

Um…you shouldn't. This assembles fine for me in MSVC's inline assembly. As we have already seen, it is equivalent to:

```
mov  eax, DWORD PTR [ebx]
```

and means that the memory location pointed to by `ebx` will be dereferenced and that `DWORD`-sized value will be loaded into `eax`.

---

> why I cant do `mov a, [eax]` Should that not make "a" a pointer to wherever eax is pointing?

No. This combination of operands is not allowed. As you can see from [the documentation for the `MOV` instruction](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_176.html), there are essentially five possibilities (ignoring alternate encodings and segments):

```
mov  register, register     ; copy one register to another
mov  register, memory       ; load value from memory into register
mov  memory,   register     ; store value from register into memory
mov  register, immediate    ; move immediate value (constant) into register
mov  memory,   immediate    ; store immediate value (constant) in memory
```

Notice that there is no `mov  memory, memory`, which is what you were trying.

However, you can make `a` point to what `eax` is pointing to by simply coding:

```
mov  DWORD PTR [a], eax
```

Now `a` and `eax` have the same value. If `eax` was a pointer, then `a` is now a pointer to that same memory location.

If you want to set `a` to the *value* that `eax` is pointing to, then you will need to do:

```
mov  eax, DWORD PTR [eax]    ; eax = *eax
mov  DWORD PTR [a], eax      ; a   = eax
```

Of course, this clobbers the pointer and replaces it with the dereferenced value. If you don't want to lose the pointer, then you will have to use a second "scratch" register; something like:

```
mov  edx, DWORD PTR [eax]    ; edx = *eax
mov  DWORD PTR [a], edx      ; a   = edx
```

---

I realize this is all somewhat confusing. The `mov` instruction is overloaded with a large number of potential meanings in the x86 ISA. This is due to x86's roots as a CISC architecture. By contrast, modern RISC architectures do a better job of separating register-register moves, memory loads, and memory stores. x86 crams them all into a single `mov` instruction. It's too late to go back and fix it now; you just have to get comfortable with the syntax, and sometimes it takes a second glance.

Comment: incredible that you can write so many paragraphs just explaining the dereference operator

Comment: *This notation is necessary in other assemblers like NASM that are not strongly-typed / You don't need this at all when dereferencing register operands* - That paragraph is backward or something and needs a rewrite.  In NASM, the *non*-memory operand being a register implies the operand-size, so you only ever need a size override with `op [mem], imm` (or with `inc [mem]` or `movzx` or `shl [mem], cl`) regardless of `[mem]` being `[edx]` or `[var]`.  And the register in the addressing mode determines address-size not operand-size.

Comment: In MASM, you may need a size override to load / store a size that doesn't match the declaration, so yes in MASM using an *addressing mode* that doesn't involve a "variable" means you don't need size overrides if the other operand being a register can imply it.  I'm pretty sure you know this (now at least), but it's not what you wrote. :/  You seem to have a different opinion than me on always including verbose operand-size specifiers, instead of only when needed, so I'm reluctant to just rewrite that whole paragraph.

Comment: Re: `mov mem,mem` not being allowed: we have a couple Q&As about that, the best canonicals IMO being [Why isn't movl from memory to memory allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33794169) / [What x86 instructions take two (or more) memory operands?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52573554)

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer is great and detailed. However, there is another aspect to mention:

`EAX` is a 32 bit register that can hold a 32 bit number, which is a double word. (lower half is AX, 16 bits or a word, and quarter are AH/AL, 8 bits or a byte)

However, `[EAX]` is a 32 bit memory address and memory locations are composed of consecutive 8 bit units. You need to specify what kind of data is hold at that location, meaning you have to give total length of the block: 8 bit `BYTE`, 16 bit `WORD`, or in this case 32 bit `DOUBLE WORD`.

```
mov eax,12345678h ; 32bit number

mov [eax],eax     ; copy the number 12345678h to (same as DOUBLE WORD)
                  ; the 12345678h-1234567Bh memory locations (4 bytes)

mov word[eax],ax  ; copy the number     5678h to
                  ; the 12345678h-12345679h memory locations (2 bytes)

mov byte[eax],ah  ; copy the number       78h to
                  ; the 12345678h memory location (1 byte)
```

note: 64 bit, or 8 bytes, the quad word, should be similar, but I haven't worked with that yet, so no comment about it.

EDIT: as per the comment below, when using registers the sizes are detected fine by (most) compilers, but if you use immediate values you need to be explicit about them.

Comment: Why omit the `dword` in `mov dword [eax], eax` but not for `mov word [eax], ax`?  None of them need it, the register source operand implies an operand-size.  The address-size implies nothing about the operand-size, so `mov [eax], 12345678h` is ambiguous, NASM will refuse to assemble it because neither operand implies an operand-size.  You should consistently either include or omit operand-size overrides for all 3 sizes.

Comment: And yes, `movq  xmm0, qword [eax]` works the same way.  Or a case that's not implied by the mnemonic, `fld qword [eax]` vs. `fld dword [eax]` are both valid.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks, compiler or version differences can be a pain, some needs explicit writing, some auto-detects.

Comment: You're using `word` not `word ptr`, so this is NASM or FASM syntax.  There are no assemblers where `[eax]` implies 32-bit operand-size for the other operand if it's not a register.  MASM need an override like `mov dword ptr [a_word_array + ecx*2], eax` to store with an element size that doesn't match the elements of the declaration, because `foo: dw 1, 2, 3, 4` magically associates `foo` with `word` size when you use it in addressing modes.  NASM isn't like that, but if the addressing mode is just registers, no symbols, not a factor anyway.

Comment: [Determining when NASM can infer the size of the mov operation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30959266) / [When do I need to specify the size of the operand in Assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64324864) / [Why do we need to disambiguate when adding an immediate value to a value at a memory address](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47445362) .  And some *bad* assemblers (8086) have a default and/or are weird: [Why operand must have size in one line but not the other in x86 assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49910109).  GNU Assembler also has a default 32-bit for non-`mov` inns in AT&T mode.