# Write data from a pointer to a local variable(another pointer) in assembler

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, masm, dosbox

```
replace PROC
    enter 8, 0
    min_i equ [bp - 2]
    min equ [bp - 4]
    max_i equ [bp - 6]
    max equ [bp - 8]

    mov bx,offset ptr_arr

    mov [min_i],[bx]
    mov [max_i],[bx]

    ...

    leave
    ret
replace ENDP
```

The program works with matrices and `ptr_arr` stores the offsets of the first row.
In `bx` there is an offset that I want to move to `min_i` and `max_i`, but the program does not compile. Compiler writes `error a2023 instruction operand must have size`.
I tried using `mov [min_i],WORD ptr bx`, but in debug is looks like `mov [bp - 2],bx` without dereference for `bx`which I need.
Is it possible to do this in 1 line without transferring `bx` to the buffer and reading from there.
I'm using masm for ms-dos. Compiling with masm+link in dosbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In asm isn't possible to copy from memory to memory(from pointer to pointer) *in one instruction*. More info here [x86 Assembly pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43769467/x86-assembly-pointers)