# Copying data from one variable to another

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

This is part of a code that I've written:

```
section .data
name db 'slm dada',0xa
lenname equ $-name
nane db 'bye '

section .text
global _start
_start:
mov edx, lenname
mov ecx, name
mov ebx, 1
mov eax, 4
int 80h

mov eax, [nane]           <- My questions are about
mov [name], dword eax     <- these 2 lines

mov edx, lenname
mov ecx, name
mov ebx, 1
mov eax, 4
int 80h

mov eax, 1
int 0x80
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Is there a way not to use the `EAX` register to move the value of the *nane* variable to the *name* variable?
2. Why do we need to use a type modifier?

Comment: If you literally just want to avoid using `eax`, then sure.  Use some other register as a temporary, like `ecx` or `edx`.

Answer (score 9):

1. **No, there is no way to do this using only a single instruction.** That is, you cannot do:

   ```
   mov  [name], [nane]     ; invalid code!
   ```

   because there is no encoding of the `MOV` instruction that takes two memory operands:

   ```
   mov  mem, meg           ; non-existent instruction!
   ```

   The only forms available for [`MOV`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_176.html) are:

   ```
   mov  reg, imm           ; place immediate/constant in register
   mov  mem, imm           ; store immediate/constant in memory
   mov  reg, reg           ; copy one register to another
   mov  reg, mem           ; load value from memory into register
   mov  mem, reg           ; store value from register into memory
   ```

   This is why you have to use a temporary register.

   There *is* actually a way to move data from one location in memory to another using a single instruction—[`MOVS`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_203.html). This uses *implicit* operands, but requires some additional setup to work properly, besides the fact that it is an inherently slow instruction (implemented with microcode), so using `MOV` with a temporary register is almost always a better idea.
2. **The type modifier should *not* be required there. And, indeed, NASM does not require it.** It assembles this code without error:

   ```
   mov  eax, [nane]
   mov  [name], eax
   ```

   Note that, if you *were* going to include a type modifier (and you always can, just to be explicit), then it should not be placed where you originally had it. The assembler already knows that the `EAX` register is `DWORD`-sized. The correct (explicit) forms would be:

   ```
   mov  eax, dword [nane]
   mov  dword [name], eax
   ```

   but, as I said, this is not actually necessary. The assembler can tell that it is to store a `DWORD` sized value at the address of `name` because the source operand (`EAX`) is itself `DWORD`-sized.

   See also this answer: [When should I use size directives in x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44577130/when-should-i-use-size-directives-in-x86/44586675#44586675)