# brk segment overflow error in x86 assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, segmentation-fault

As a beginner in assembly x86, I started to code a program, a keygenme like,
like in CTF challenges. So I wrote a very basic one with all strings encoded but xored etc... At the moment it's absolutly easy to reverse but that's not my problem. For copple hours during, I have a segmentation fault at the very early beginning.
As is did not change anything in between, I launched it with Valgrind and he found a `brk segment overflow`. Could you help me to find the problem ? I am not really familiar with the concept of brk segment yet.
Here is my code :

```
%define BUFF_IN_SIZE 64
%define PAGE_SIZE   4096
%define SIGTRAP     5
%define PROT_READ   0x1     ; for mmap
%define PROT_WRITE  0x2     ; pour mmap ah non

%macro print 2              ; macro for syscall write
    mov     eax, 4
    mov     ebx, 1
    mov     ecx, %1
    mov     edx, %2
    int     0x80
%endmacro

%macro input 2          ; syscall read
    mov     eax, 3
    mov     ebx, 0
    mov     ecx, %1
    mov     edx, %2
    int     0x80
%endmacro

%macro exit 0
    xor     ebx, ebx 
    mov     eax, 1
    int     0x80
%endmacro        

section .bss
    buffinp     resb    128
    bufftemp    resb    64
    buffhello   resb    64
    errbuff     resb    64
    keysclear   resw    4
    xorkey      resw    1
    leninput    resb    1
    xorlen      resb    1
    errlen      resb    1
    keyindex    resb    1
    dummy       resb    1 

; welcome = "Password : "
; cryflag = encrypted password
; successdone = "This is the flag"
; fail = "Wrong password !"
section .data
    cryflag     dw      0x14D2, 0x1533, 0x17F4, 0x1735, 0x14B6, 0x17F7, 0x1738, 0x1459, 0x153A, 0x141B, 0x153C, 0x157D, 0x153E, 0x145F, 0x1520, 0x1501
    welcome     dw      0x0954, 0x0655, 0x0996, 0x0637, 0x0C38, 0x0E19, 0x0C5A, 0x0C5B, 0x0CDC, 0x0FDD, 0x0C7E, 0x0EBF, 0x0640, 0x0501, 0x0642
    succesdone  dw      0x3721, 0x30A2, 0x3263, 0x3804, 0x3825, 0x3806, 0x3687, 0x3108, 0x30A9, 0x380A, 0x30CB, 0x318C, 0x302D, 0x30EE, 0x380F, 0x3130, 0x3271, 0x3812, 0x3B53, 0x3814
    fail        dw      0x0C86, 0x0827, 0x0B88, 0x0BA9, 0x0A8A, 0x026B, 0x086C, 0x0A4D, 0x080E, 0x080F, 0x0890, 0x0B91, 0x0832, 0x0AF3, 0x0274, 0x0255
    ; keys = array of each xor key
    keys        dw      0x234, 0x3c01, 0x666, 0x1992
    debug       db      "Reached this part !", 0xa, 0
    lendbg      equ     $ - debug

section .text
    global strlen
    global strcmp
    global asciisum
    global xordecrypt
    global checkvm
    global handler

    global _start

_start:
    ; use it  only when it will be a ctf
    mov     eax, 48         ; sys_signal
    mov     ebx, SIGTRAP    ; SIGTRAP for int 0x3
    mov     ecx, handler    ; it exits
    int     0x80
    
    ; decrypt array of word to array of bytes for each string
    mov esi, fail
    mov edi, errbuff
    mov ebx, 0x666
    mov byte [xorlen], 16
    call xordecrypt
    mov byte [errlen], 16

    ; second string
    mov esi, welcome
    mov edi, buffhello
    mov ebx, 0x234
    mov byte [xorlen], 15

    ;********************** segmentation fault here 
    call xordecrypt

    ; prints the loggin message
    print   buffhello, [xorlen]

    ; waiting for the response of user
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, buffinp
    mov edx, BUFF_IN_SIZE

.invalid:
    mov eax, 3
    int 0x80
    cmp byte [ecx + eax - 1], 0xa ; check if LF is last in buffer input
    je .exitinput       ; yes, the input is valid
    mov ecx, dummy      ; otherwise flushing the buffer
    mov edx, 1          ; and segfault if overflowing dummy byte
    jmp .invalid

.exitinput:             ; compute size of user input
    mov edi, buffinp
    call strlen
    test al, al
    jz .failure
    mov byte [leninput], al

    ; decrypting the harcoded encrypted password here
    mov byte [xorlen], al
    mov esi, cryflag
    mov edi, bufftemp
    mov ebx, 0x1992
    call xordecrypt

    ; compares it with the user one
    mov esi, buffinp
    mov edi, bufftemp
    mov ecx, 16 ;[xorlen]
    call strcmp
    test al, al
    jnz .failure

    ; success in this case
    mov esi, succesdone
    mov edi, bufftemp
    mov ebx, 0x3c01
    mov byte [xorlen], 20
    call xordecrypt
    print edi, [xorlen]
    exit

; priting wrong password and exiting
.failure:
    print   errbuff, [errlen]
    exit

; strlen implementation with any control char terminated strings
strlen:
    push    ecx
    xor     ecx, ecx

.strlen_next:
    cmp     [edi + ecx], byte 0x16 ; below 20 so 0, \n all works
    jb      .strlen_null        
    inc     ecx
    jo      .strlen_over
    jmp     .strlen_next

.strlen_over:
    print errbuff, [errlen]
    exit

.strlen_null:
    mov     eax, ecx
    pop     ecx
    ret

; basic strcmp without any obfuscation
; eax = 0 if equals
strcmp:
    cld
    repe    cmpsb
    jcxz    .retcmp
    jmp     .failcmp

.failcmp:               ; fail ? set up ecx on != 0
    or      ecx, 0x1
    jno     .retcmp     ; jmp like so
    xchg    ax, ax

.retcmp:
    mov     eax, ecx
    ret

; *************************************
; esi = addresse du word array source
; edi = addresse du byte array dest
; bx = xor key
; ************************************
xordecrypt:
    xor     ecx, ecx
    xor     edx, edx

.decrypting:
    mov     ax, word [esi + edx * 2]
    xor     ax, bx                  ; first xoring with key
    mov     cl, 5
    shr     ax, cl                  ; right shift of 5 to get a byte
    mov     byte [edi + edx], al    ; copy the bytes in array destination
    inc     edx
    inc     bx                      ; the key is incremented
    cmp     edx, [xorlen]
    je      .xendecrypt
    jmp     .decrypting

.xendecrypt:                        ; end decrypt
    xor     ebx, ebx
    ret

; not used here (compute ascii sum of string)
asciisum:
    push    ebx
    xor     ecx, ecx
    xor     ebx, ebx

.summing:
    mov     al, byte [esi + ecx]
    add     ebx, eax
    inc     ecx
    cmp     ecx, edx
    je      .retsum
    jmp     .summing

.retsum:
    mov     eax, ebx
    pop     ebx
    ret

; looking for guest VM enabled or not
checkvm:
    xor eax, eax
    or eax, 1
    cpuid               ; cpuid with eax = 1

    mov edx, ecx        ; stores ecx value in edx
    mov cl, 15
    shr edx, cl         ; set the vm bit in 16th
    and edx, 0x8000     ; masks the lower ones
    jnz .vmyes          ; ZF == 0 ? VM guest or return
    ret

.vmyes:     ; VM guest ? exiting
    exit

handler:    ; handler that not exits when SIGTRAP (for int 0x3)
    nop     ; waiting a little
    xchg ax, ax
    ret

; we compute the size of entire file
filesize equ $ - $$
```

And here is the valgrind report :

```
==84180== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==84180== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==84180== Using Valgrind-3.18.1-42b08ed5bd-20211015 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==84180== Command: ./keygenme
==84180== Parent PID: 1467
==84180== 
--84180-- 
--84180-- Valgrind options:
--84180--    --leak-check=full
--84180--    --show-leak-kinds=all
--84180--    --track-origins=yes
--84180--    --verbose
--84180--    --log-file=xxxvllllllllalgrind-out.txt
--84180-- Contents of /proc/version:
--84180--   Linux version 5.18.0-kali2-amd64 (devel@kali.org) (gcc-11 (Debian 11.3.0-3) 11.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.38) #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 5.18.5-1kali1 (2022-06-20)
--84180-- 
--84180-- Arch and hwcaps: X86, LittleEndian, x86-mmxext-sse1-sse2-sse3-lzcnt
--84180-- Page sizes: currently 4096, max supported 4096
--84180-- Valgrind library directory: /usr/libexec/valgrind
--84180-- Reading syms from /home/hackneolys/Documents/Prog/C/learning/Assembly/keygenme
--84180--    object doesn't have a dynamic symbol table
--84180-- Reading syms from /usr/libexec/valgrind/memcheck-x86-linux
--84180--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/d8/9dade77ff7a116220489c1e8df98cd7e123687.debug ..
--84180--   .. build-id is valid
--84180--    object doesn't have a dynamic symbol table
--84180-- Scheduler: using generic scheduler lock implementation.
--84180-- Reading suppressions file: /usr/libexec/valgrind/default.supp
==84180== embedded gdbserver: reading from /tmp/vgdb-pipe-from-vgdb-to-84180-by-hackneolys-on-???
==84180== embedded gdbserver: writing to   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-to-vgdb-from-84180-by-hackneolys-on-???
==84180== embedded gdbserver: shared mem   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-shared-mem-vgdb-84180-by-hackneolys-on-???
==84180== 
==84180== TO CONTROL THIS PROCESS USING vgdb (which you probably
==84180== don't want to do, unless you know exactly what you're doing,
==84180== or are doing some strange experiment):
==84180==   /usr/bin/vgdb --pid=84180 ...command...
==84180== 
==84180== TO DEBUG THIS PROCESS USING GDB: start GDB like this
==84180==   /path/to/gdb ./keygenme
==84180== and then give GDB the following command
==84180==   target remote | /usr/bin/vgdb --pid=84180
==84180== --pid is optional if only one valgrind process is running
==84180== 
==84180== Invalid read of size 2
==84180==    at 0x80491A4: ??? (in /home/hackneolys/Documents/Prog/C/learning/Assembly/keygenme)
==84180==  Address 0x804b000 is 0 bytes after the brk data segment limit 0x804b000
==84180== 
==84180== Invalid read of size 2
==84180==    at 0x80491A6: ??? (in /home/hackneolys/Documents/Prog/C/learning/Assembly/keygenme)
==84180==  Address 0x804b002 is 2 bytes after the brk data segment limit 0x804b000
==84180== 
==84180== Invalid write of size 1
==84180==    at 0x8049198: ??? (in /home/hackneolys/Documents/Prog/C/learning/Assembly/keygenme)
==84180==  Address 0x804b000 is 0 bytes after the brk data segment limit 0x804b000
==84180== 
==84180== 
==84180== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==84180==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x804C000
==84180==    at 0x80491A4: ??? (in /home/hackneolys/Documents/Prog/C/learning/Assembly/keygenme)
==84180==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==84180==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==84180==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==84180==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==84180==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==84180== 
==84180== HEAP SUMMARY:
==84180==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==84180==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==84180== 
==84180== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==84180== 
==84180== ERROR SUMMARY: 2389 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==84180== 
==84180== 340 errors in context 1 of 3:
==84180== Invalid write of size 1
==84180==    at 0x8049198: ??? (in /home/.../Documents/Prog/C/learning/Assembly/keygenme)
==84180==  Address 0x804b000 is 0 bytes after the brk data segment limit 0x804b000
==84180== 
==84180== 
==84180== 1024 errors in context 2 of 3:
==84180== Invalid read of size 2
==84180==    at 0x80491A6: ??? (in /home/.../Documents/Prog/C/learning/Assembly/keygenme)
==84180==  Address 0x804b002 is 2 bytes after the brk data segment limit 0x804b000
==84180== 
==84180== 
==84180== 1025 errors in context 3 of 3:
==84180== Invalid read of size 2
==84180==    at 0x80491A4: ??? (in /home/.../Documents/Prog/C/learning/Assembly/keygenme)
==84180==  Address 0x804b000 is 0 bytes after the brk data segment limit 0x804b000
==84180== 
==84180== ERROR SUMMARY: 2389 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: `cmp edx, [xorlen]` is using a 32 bit compare but `xorlen` is a single byte only.

Comment: Thanks you Jester ! I missed it. And now it works nice.

Comment: [When should I use size directives in x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44577130) isn't a perfect duplicate, but this is nearly a typo that has little to do with `brk`, and could be found with a debugger if you knew what to look for.  There have been better duplicates but they're notoriously hard to find again with google, since the question title is never about the actual problem, just some kind of crash, overwriting memory, or compare not working.