# Assembly: What does register in square brackets means?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

```
lea RAX var
mov [RAX] 12
```

If RAX is now pointing to the address of the 'var' variable. then what does [RAX] mean. ?

Comment: [What do square brackets mean in x86 assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48608423/995714)

Comment: You won't get very far as an assembly language programmer if you ignore the need for commas like that!

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you’re asking about Intel-style x86 assembly. Square brackets means ‘the variable at the memory address stored in RAX”.

So:

```
mov RAX, 12
```

means “store value 12 into RAX”

```
mov [RAX], 12
```

means “store value 12 in the memory cell whose address is stored in RAX’

Comment: In most assemblers, `mov [rax], 12` is an error: ambiguous operand-size.  `You'd need `mov byte [rax], 12` to write just one addressable unit of memory.

Comment: Right, also my memories are from rusty old 16/32bit tasm / nasm. I think it was even byte ptr [rax] ...?

Comment: `byte ptr` is TASM / MASM (and GNU `.intel_syntax noprefix`).  `byte` is NASM / FASM.  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/intel-syntax/info / [When should I use size directives in x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44577130) / [Determining when NASM can infer the size of the mov operation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30959266)